# Reading input after child process receives SIGTSTP in a Ruby shell

Tags: ruby, shell, unix, signals

The below ruby code exhibits an issue where the parent process that resumes after its child is suspended (SIGTSTP) doesn't actually receive input until after the character entered.

Here are the steps two reproduce with the below code:

- Run the below `repl.rb` which will echo what you print unless you enter "irb".
- Type "irb" to launch a new irb process.
- Hit Ctrl-Z to send SIGTSTP to stop the irb process.
- You'll be brought back to the main repl. You are even provided a prompt.
- Type "foo", hit enter. You'll be echoed "oo".
- Type "foo" again, hit enter. You'll see "foo".
- Type "exit" to exit the program. Once your program exits the missing "f" will be printed.
- Why does the first "f" not come thru the first time and come after the program exits?

Here's the source to `repl.rb`:

```
Signal.trap("SIGTSTP", "IGNORE")

pids = []
stty_save = `stty -g`
loop do
  print "#{$0}> "
  input = STDIN.gets.chomp
  if input == "exit"
    exit
  else
    command = nil
    if input == "irb"
      command = "irb"
    elsif input == "fg" && pids.last
      Process.kill "SIGCONT", pids.last
    else
      puts input
      next
    end
    if command
      pid = fork do
        Signal.trap("SIGTSTP", "DEFAULT")
        exec command
      end
      pids << pid
    end
    pid, status = Process.waitpid2 pids.last, Process::WUNTRACED if pids.last
    if status.stopsig == 18 # stopped
      system "stty", stty_save
      puts "Stopped"
    else
      pids.pop
    end
  end
end
```

Here's what I got:

```
/tmp  ➜ ruby repl.rb
repl.rb> foo
foo
repl.rb> irb
>> Stopped
repl.rb> foo
oo
repl.rb> exit
f/tmp  ➜
```

Here's what I expected:

```
/tmp  ➜ ruby repl.rb
repl.rb> foo
foo
repl.rb> irb
>> Stopped
repl.rb> foo
foo
repl.rb> exit
/tmp  ➜
```

#### Update

This works fine on Linux (or at least Ubuntu 14.04.1). My host machine that is exhibiting the issue is OS X running Yosemite.

On Linux the the parent process receives the signal number 20 instead of 18 (as on OS X).

Comment: A similar issue exists if you replace the "irb" command with "ruby input.rb" and then in "input.rb" place the following code: "loop do {  gets }", but now it won't actually read any character until you enter, then it will start reading.